# How to set UIViewController background image to fill screen

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, background

I have a `UIViewController` that I want to set the background to one image. I want to do this in code not `IB`, so I can subsequently change the image.

Having read all the tips on here about `.ScaleAspectFill` my image still does not resize to fit the screen. Can anyone offer any advice please? The code I have is:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // set the inital backgroundColor
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: gameBackgroundOne!)
    self.view.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill //doesnt seem to do anything!
    self.view.clipsToBounds = true // is this needed?
    self.view.center = view.center // is this needed?
}
```

Comment: where do you set the background image?

Comment: the background image is set elsewhere. that part is working ok, as some part of the image is showing, but its not filling correctly

Answer (score 5):

It would be best to create a separate UIImageView for this.

```
var imageView: UIImageView!

override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()

    // get the correct image out of your assets cataloge
    let image = UIImage(named: "yourImageInAssets")!

    // initialize the value of imageView with a CGRectZero, resize it later
    self.imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectZero)

    // set the appropriate contentMode and add the image to your imageView property
    self.imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
    self.imageView.image = image

    // add the imageView to your view hierarchy
    self.view.addSubview(imageView)
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    //set the frame of your imageView here to automatically adopt screen size changes (e.g. by rotation or splitscreen)
    self.imageView.frame = self.view.bounds

}
```

Comment: I just changed the last line in loadView() method to: self.imageView.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds (so it works for me). Might help to someone...

Answer (score 1):

Create an image view, add the image to the image view and add the image view to your view hierarchy.

```
override viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: self.view.bounds)
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "your image name")//if its in images.xcassets
    self.view.addSubview(imageView)
}
```